# Name for the centre position of a sine wave

Tags: signal-processing

As an engineer of some years, I'm slightly puzzled and embarrassed to be asking this question, but I genuinely can't find an answer elsewhere.

Consider a [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave).  Every example has it oscillating about a Y position of zero, which for the sine wave in isolation makes perfect sense.

Suppose it is not oscillating about a Y position of zero though, but about some other point in Y.  To generalise, this could be a constant position, or a position moving arbitrarily as defined by some other function.  This position would be the centre of the sine wave as a periodic waveform (i.e. the mean 
 - whether arithmetic, least-squares or some other method - as duration tends to infinity).  Starting/finishing phase is not relevant.

#### What do we call this Y offset from zero in the context of the sine wave?  Does it have a name?

To generalise further, I suspect this will be general for any periodic waveform and not just a sine wave, but I'm writing a document which is particularly considering sine waves so I would be happy with an answer in that context.

The best I can come up with is "centre" or "offset", neither of which I'm particularly happy with, but I'm not aware of a better term for the concept and I can't find anything online.  Hence asking on here!

Note that this is ***not*** modulation - the sine wave amplitude, frequency and phase are unchanged.

Comment: I would call it the (DC) bias.

Answer (score 0):

The term I'm familiar with for this is equilibrium position. [image]

Comment: In the United States high schools, we call that the midline, and I think we also tend to conflate the line with its y-value.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks.  I guess that could fit for a constant offset, but I'm not sure it's more descriptive than "centre".  It also doesn't fit the general case for the centre being a moving target - consider the slinky-plus-mass being mounted on an elevator, for example, where the elevator's movement sums with the basic slinky oscillation.