# Name for the center amplitude of a sine wave

Tags: terminology, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am trying to find the name for the value at the center of a sine wave
$$
y(t) = A\sin (kx \pm \omega t+\varphi) + D
$$
i.e. the offset $D$ of the wave in the $y$-direction. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) calls it *Center Amplitude*, but further googling this name is difficult and does not provide any further sources. I also found the expression [Center Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_frequency), but I'm not sure that it refers to the same thing.
Is there a commonly used name for the $y$-direction-offset of a sine wave?

Comment: Googling "center amplitude" reveals page after page of articles that use the term in precisely the sense defined by Wikipedia.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Name for the centre position of a sine wave](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430871/1508).

Answer (score 1):

In signal processing (more precisely in relation with [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)), it may be called *average* or *mean value*.
In relationship with [oscilloscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope), the *steady component* is called (DC) *offset*.